# Azure Face API SDK overloads with and without HTTP headers

Tags: c#, azure, sdk, face-api

The C# SDK for the [Microsoft Azure Face API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face) provides methods like `PersonGroupPerson.GetAsync` and `PersonGroupPerson.GetWithHttpMessagesAsync`.

There are two significant differences:

- The `WithHttpMessagesAsync` variant allows you to specify HTTP headers.  Why would you want to do that in a call to the Azure Face API?
- The `Async` variant does not return the `HttpOperationResponse`.  But the `Async` variants call the `WithHttpMessagesAsync` variants anyway.  And looking at [the source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/cognitiveservices/Vision.Face/src/Generated/PersonGroupPerson.cs) it appears that if the response isn't 200 it throws an `APIErrorException` exception anyway.  So the returned value is pretty useless.

So why would you ever choose to use the `WithHttpMessagesAsync` variant?

Comment: I've also raised this question as an issue on the Github repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/6543

Comment: MS have replied to the above issue and raised an issue on the AutoRest documentation generation tool, to add the requested clarification.  https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/3282